# Two elements getting on top of each other on zoom in

Tags: html, css

As the title says: I have two elements (images) that get on top of each other when I zoom in.the img on the left is the logo and the one on the right is a leaderboard size image.

```html
<div style="max-height:90px;margin-bottom:20px;display:block;">

  <p style="max-height:90px;width:330px;float:left;">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="#" />
    </a>
  </p>

  <p style="float:right;">
    <a href="#" target="_top">
      <img src="#" width="728" max-height="90" alt="Image" border="0" />
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't post spam links.

Comment: You need to use `@media` queries for this...

Comment: How do you 'zoom in'? Are you using the browser's own zoom functionality or something else? Your question is unclear. Perhaps you should post an example of what it looks like versus how you would like it to look.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the left image is of fixed width and the right leaderboard ad would have a variable width. It is better to use a fixed-fluid layout using `positions` for this:

```css
header {position: relative; padding-left: 110px;}
header h1 {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; margin: 0;}
a, img {vertical-align: top; display: inline-block;}
header aside img {max-width: 100%;}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="//placehold.it/100x50?text=Logo" />
    </a>
  </h1>
  <aside>
    <a href="#" target="_top">
      <img src="//placehold.it/728x90" width="728" alt="Leader Ad" />
    </a>
  </aside>
</header>
```

However you zoom, it retains it well:

**Normal View**

[image]

**Zoomed In View**

[image]